# Software Riddle [Part 4!]

Tags: riddle

```
 This riddle is a computer language. Enjoy!
```

My name is a dictionary word
Built on microcomputers
I'm general purpose
My syntax is short, but easy

I once was the "beginner" language
My GOTO is very popular
Made in 1964-by Hampshians
I was very high-level

> Tear every line apart for full credit!

Comment: Did I post too quickly or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

> BASIC

My name is a dictionary word

> Basic is an English word

Built on microcomputers

> It was widely used on microcomputers in the 70s and 80s.

I'm general purpose

> Can be used to write all kinds of programs.

My syntax is short, but easy

> There are not too many keywords, and they are easy to learn.

I once was the "beginner" language

> BASIC stands for Beginner's All-purpose Symbolic Instruction Code.

My GOTO is very popular

> The GOTO statement is used in many other languages too.

Made in 1964-by Hampshians

> Invented by Kemeny and Kurtz of Dartmouth College in New Hampshire.

I was very high-level

> A high level programming language that abstracts you away from computer specific details.

Comment: Nice!  You did it quickly :)